# Forced JRE version in JNLP doesn't work on java 1.7

Tags: security, java, jnlp, java-web-start

I am forcing the JRE version in my JNLP file with the following statement:

```xml
<j2se version="1.5.0_12" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" initial-heap-size="128m" max-heap-size="512m"/>
```

It was blocking fine when the user tried to open it and has the java 1.6, but if the user has the java 1.7, the system doesn't block. The user is prompted if he wants to download the web start application using the JRE 1.7 and he can indeed open my application.

Anyone knows about this issue that appeared with java 1.7 and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Note that Oracle removed the JRE auto-download feature from Web Start in 2013: [openjdk bug 8006701](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8006701). Web Start now often (but not always) silently ignores the version specification.

Answer (score 1):

```xml
<j2se version="1.5.0_12" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" initial-heap-size="128m" max-heap-size="512m"/>
```

According to the download page, even 1.5 is up to [JRE v. 1.5.0_22](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html#jre-1.5.0_22-oth-JPR).

Improvements (probably to security) have been made to the JRE since then.  I would have expected that the user was being warned of a web-start app. requesting an earlier and possibly insecure JRE.  That is, until 1.7.0_22, in which Oracle seems to have 'cracked down' on a number of potential security problems.

> Anyone .. knows how to fix it?

The 'fix' it to update your app. to being capable of being run in..

See [Java 7 Update 21 Security Improvements in Detail](http://blog.eisele.net/2013/04/java-7-update-21-security-improvements.html) for info.

As to 'how to fix it', I'd say update(?) the app. to be compatible with..

```xml
<j2se version="1.5.0_12+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" initial-heap-size="128m" max-heap-size="512m"/>
```